# html5 - canvas mouse up event not triggered

Tags: html, html5-canvas

In canvas, mousedown and mousemove  works fine, but mouseup event not been triggered in below sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <head> <style type="text/css"> body {background: #eee;} </style> </head>
<body>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <canvas id="video-canvas" width=320 height=240 style="background:#000;"></canvas>
    </div>
    <pre align="left" id="log"></pre>
    <script>
        function Logger(id) {this.el = document.getElementById('log');}
        Logger.prototype.log = function(msg) {
            var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
            fragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
            fragment.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
            this.el.appendChild(fragment);
        };
        Logger.prototype.clear = function() {this.el.textContent = '';};
        var logger = new Logger('log');
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var logelem = document.getElementById("log");
        var canvas = document.getElementById('video-canvas');
        function getMousePos(canvasDom, mouseEvent) {
            var rect = canvasDom.getBoundingClientRect();
            var scaleX = canvas.width / rect.width; 
            var scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height; 
            var x = (mouseEvent.clientX - rect.left)*scaleX;
            var y = (mouseEvent.clientY - rect.top)*scaleY;
            return {
                x: mouseEvent.clientX - rect.left,
                y: mouseEvent.clientY - rect.top
            };
        }
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
            logger.log("down " + mousePos.x + "," + mousePos.y);
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            logger.log("up " + mousePos.x + "," + mousePos.y);
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            //logger.log("move " + mousePos.x + "," + mousePos.y);
            var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
        }, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you missing: `var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, e);` for mouseup function?

Comment: @elszeus Oh, you are right! after fix that, it works now! Thanks!